# Removing class from last clicked event in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a Navbar with tabs, and I want to make a function called onClick that gets the event, and adds a class to that tab "active". But, when I click another tab, it should remove a class from the previous tab and add it to that one.

**Sample of my code:**

```
const [clickedTab, setClickedTab] = useState(true);

function Click() {

  if (clickedTab === true) {
    console.log(clickedTab);
    tab.classList.add("active");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In React use the model (via `useState()` in this case) to make changes to the view.

Set the `activeId` of the tab in the state, and if the tab's `id` is equal to `activeId` pass set it's `active` to `true`. The tab itself can add/remove the `className`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Tab = ({ id, active, setActive }) => (
  <li 
    className={`tab ${active ? 'active' : ''}`}
    onClick={() => setActive(id)}
    >
    {id}
  </li>
);

const Example = ({ tabs }) =>  {
  const [activeId, setActive] = useState(); 
  
  return (
    <ul className="tabs">
    {tabs.map(id => (
      <Tab
        key={id}
        id={id}
        setActive={setActive} 
        active={id === activeId}
      />
    ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

const tabs = [1, 2, 3, 4];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example tabs={tabs} />,
  root
);
```

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab {
  height: 1em;
  width: 2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is useful but I don't know how can I combine this with my code because beside adding className and removing it, it must also route pages.
I have 4 links and here is the example of one of them:
**<Link style={style} to ="/">
              <li>Home</li>
              </Link>**

Comment: If you're using react router look at [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example so you can get the idea; we hold current active element id in a `state` then based on that we decide what class name it should have; no need to use `classList`'s `add` or `remove`

```js
function Header () {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState();
  return (
    <header>
      <ul>
       <li 
         className={active === 1? "red":"blue"}
         onClick={()=>setActive(1)}
       >a</li>       
       <li 
         className={active === 2? "red":"blue"}
         onClick={()=>setActive(2)}
       >b</li>
       <li 
         className={active === 3? "red":"blue"}
         onClick={()=>setActive(3)}
       >c</li>
      </ul>
     </header>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Header />, app );
```

```css
.red{background:red}.blue{background:blue}li{color:#fff;width:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Can I somehow shorten that and remove repetition but combine it with this example:
**<Link style={style} to ="/">
              <li className={active === 1? "active" : "inactive"}
      onClick={() => setActive(1)}>Home</li>
              </Link>** ?